# Excludes xml file on publish ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I have an API service for my blog engine. I have integrated OpenAPI documentations with swagger to my API but ended up with rather peculiar problem to my perspective. In the project root directory there is a file called APIService.xml, which is actually xml document specifications. This API is deployed in Azure through Azure CI/CD pipelines. API deployed successfully, however when i try to run this api, it won't because it is actually looking for apiservice.xml file therefore failed to run because said file won't include in the project. I initially thoughts it might be issue with Azure DevOps pipelines, therefore I tried to publish it locally but file is not there, which means it is not getting published/included in the project on publish. I have tried to add it manually in Kudu console, but it won't add whatsoever. What is the way to add this file on publish? is there any settings that i should look at.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys, I got it fixed by adding one liner setting in my csproj file:-

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

However, m pretty curious why would i need to add this additional line unnecessarily, shouldn't such files be added automatically on publish where is it needed for the project to run.

Thanks!!

Comment: How do you think should `dotnet` know, if the xml documentation is needed for the project to run?

Comment: Since my csproj file has already added with :-   <DocumentationFile>APIService.xml</DocumentationFile> then why would i need to enter additional lines, why shouldn't Asp.Net Core would understand the line and do the stuff whatever is required is my point. I have already told my asp.net core project that my apiservice.xml is my documentation file, so let's add this file but unfortunately it fails to understand.